# Docker pull fails with "Tag latest not found in repository" even when "latest" tag exists

Tags: docker

I tried to pull the Fedora docker image using the following command but it failed with `Tag latest not found in repository docker.io/library/fedora` error:

```
# docker pull fedora
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/fedora
62b0615068df: Pull complete 
cd1e9127a3f8: Verifying Checksum 
Pulling repository docker.io/library/fedora
Tag latest not found in repository docker.io/library/fedora
```

However, it succeeded when I pulled it with the `latest` tag explicitly specified.

```
docker pull fedora:latest
latest: Pulling from library/fedora
cd1e9127a3f8: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:52db7a1a18f173622a9b1a75354c7266220bffb7187c4880590805af0d7679d6
Status: Downloaded newer image for fedora:latest
```

In an attempt to understand this further, I tried to pull the CentOS docker image. However, I did not see this behavior in case of CentOS:

```
docker pull centos
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/centos
Digest: sha256:1a62cd7c773dd5c6cf08e2e28596f6fcc99bd97e38c9b324163e0da90ed27562
Status: Downloaded newer image for centos:latest
```

**Version Info**

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)
# docker -v
Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5
```

Can someone please help me understand this behavior?

Comment: That could be a bug, there's a discussion about that here https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/5047 and pulling the :latest image should be the default behaviour when a tag is not specified.

Comment: Any news on this? I have a similar issue on a private registry that keeps saying it can't find the tag "latest".

Comment: @Nicky - Unfortunately the problem disappeared after a couple of days in my case (and without doing any config changes). I never really understood what was causing the issue.

Comment: @Amit I guess the worst part is that the source of the issue is still unknown.I tried other things like adding tags to both my Docker Hub registry and on Docker Cloud, but somehow the issue persists and I'm out of options.

Comment: I've been witnessing what looks like a similar issue, but with image centos:7: `Tag 7 not found in repository docker.io/library/centos`. I tried re-pulling just after and it worked fine. It's not the 1st time I witness this issue. I am also running docker 1.9.1 build a34a1d5

Answer (score 4):

Looks like Docker is handling network errors in a wrong way. E.g. DNS timeout may be reported as "Tag xxx not found". That's why an error may be intermittent. Saw that few times, changing DNS server to google DNS (8.8.8.8) and waiting for few minutes fixed this docker error for me.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly my problem too.  Now, I must figure out why the bind server works for everything except this (suddenly).

Answer (score 1):

While it looks like the original problem was handled, I was running into the same error message and it turns out the issue was I was running an old version (1.8.3) of docker on my system (version from the Debian/Rasperian apt repository). When I removed that version and installed the current version (18.09.0) from docker.io, I am now able to pull the image. Hopefully that helps anyone else that gets this error message if it's not just a transient network issue.